# Optimizing tensor multiplications

Tags: matlab, numpy, dot-product, numpy-einsum

I've got a real-time image processing program I'm trying to optimize, and it all boils down to matrix multiplications. Consider 3 tensors I'm calculating in the initialization stage:

1. `A = np.arange(35 * 51 * 59).reshape([35, 51, 59])`
2. `B = np.arange(37 * 51 * 51 * 59).reshape([37, 51, 51, 59])`
3. `C = np.arange(59 * 27).reshape([59, 27])`

Each frame, I'm getting a new data in the form of a fourth tensor:

- `M = np.arange(35 * 37 * 59).reshape([35, 37, 59])`.

Currently, I'm calculating `D = np.einsum('xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr', M, A, B, C)`, where `D` is my desired result, and it's the major bottleneck of the program. There are two directions I'm trying to follow in order to optimize it.

First I tried coming up with a tensor `T`, a function of `A, B, C, D` that I can pre-calculate, and then it'll all boil to `D = np.tensordot(M, T, axes=..)`. I wasn't successful. I spent a lot of time on it, is it even possible at all?

Moreover, the program itself is written in MATLAB. As it doesn't have a built-in tensor multiplication function (`einsum` or `tensordot` equivilent), I'm currently using  the `tprod` toolbox, and doing:

```
temp1 = etprod('dcb', A, 'abc', M, 'adc');
temp2 = etprod('dbc', B, 'abcd', temp1, 'adb');
D = etprod('cdb', C, 'ab', temp2, 'acd');
```

As the default dot product function in MATLAB (for 2D matrices) is much faster then `etprod`, I though about reshaping `A, B, C, D` to 2D arrays in a way that I will able to multiple 2D matrices using the default function, without hand-written `for` loops. I wasn't successful with that either.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Do a search on `einsum` and you'll find discussions of alternatives and speeds. Your expression is so complex that we can't give simple alternatives, You'll have to experiment.  But for a start I'd suggest  breaking it into several expressions.

Comment: Could you describe what that call to `einsum` computes? I might be able to provide an efficient MATLAB alternative.

Comment: `opt_einsum` now supports constant arguments: http://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reusing_paths.html#specifying-constants. This will automatically find the correct order.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55913093/3372061

Answer (score 1):

If this operation is done many times with different values of M we could define

```
D0 = np.einsum('xft,fr->tpr',A, B, C)
```

The whole operation could be broken into binary steps:

```
D0=np.einsum('xtf,ytpf->xyptf',A,B)
D0=np.einsum('xyptf,fr->xyftpr',D0,C)
D=np.einsum('tprxfy,xfy->tpr',D0,M)
```

The final operation uses D0 and M and can be coded as a matrix vector operation. In Matlab it would be

```
D=reshape(D0.[],numel(M))*M(:);
```

which could then be reordered as desired.
We could write this order as (((A,B),C),M)

It might be better, however, to use ((M,C),A,B)

```
D=np.einsum('xyf,fr->xyfr',M,C)
D0=np.einsum('xyfr,xtf->ytfr',D,A)
D=np.einsum('ytfr,ytpf->tpr',D,B)
```

This ordering of operations has intermediate arrays with only 4 indices rather than one with 6. If each operation is much faster than the single one this may be an advantage.