# Translating np.einsum() to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, permutation, ellipsis, code-translation, numpy-einsum

I am having trouble understanding the [documentation of `np.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). How are `subscripts` interpreted?

I am trying to write `np.einsum('a...c,b...c', Y, conj(Y))` where `Y` is a matrix of shape `C, F, T` on the original python. Also, due to previous implementation differences my MATLAB `Y` is of size `[F, T, C]`.

What does `'a...c,b...c'` index in each component? I am confused.

How do I write the same instructions in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you look for questions on this topic on SO? One example - [Element-wise matrix multiplication for multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55913093/3372061)

Comment: I did but I missed your link. I am reading through it now.

Comment: It does not help me. For example, I do not understand why is 'mki' is `5,3,1`. what do these letters represent? are these indices of 'A'? If so, Arent they supposed to be `2,2,2000`?

Comment: Those letter represent the different dimension of the array.

Comment: If you missed it, you must not have used the "search by tag" feature, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab+numpy-einsum) of searching for [tag:matlab]+[tag:numpy-einsum] (which returns 5 question including this one and the one I linked). `5,3,1` is the order of dimensions. So if one has a matrix of size `[20,3,500,100,4,2]` it refers to the dimension of size 2, then the one of size 100 and finally the one of size 3 (considering python's 0-based indexing).

Comment: So, does `a..c` refers to dimensions `0,1,2` and `b...c` refers to dimensions `1,2`?

Comment: Both `Y` and `Y.conj()` are 3d arrays of the same shape, so `a...c` is an implicit `aic` and `b...c` is an implicit `bic`, and the missing `->...` makes it equivalent to `aic, bic -> iab`. This in turn is the same as `(Y.transpose(1, 2, 0)[..., None] * Y.conj().transpose(1, 2, 0)[:, :, None, :]).sum(1)`: turn the first array's `[F, T, C]` shape into `[T, C, F, 1]` and the second into `[T, C, 1, F]` which broadcast to `[T, C, F, F]`, finally sum over the second dimension to get `[T, F, F]` which is hopefully exactly what you get. I'd be explicit in the `einsum` call to make it readable.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from the `einsum` documentation page:

> To enable and control broadcasting, use an ellipsis. Default NumPy-style broadcasting is done by adding an ellipsis to the left of each term, like `np.einsum('...ii->...i', a)`. To take the trace along the first and last axes, you can do `np.einsum('i...i', a)`, or to do a matrix-matrix product with the left-most indices instead of rightmost, one can do `np.einsum('ij...,jk...->ik...', a, b)`.

Later, an example is given:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
>>> np.einsum('...j->...', a)
array([ 10,  35,  60,  85, 110])
```

The equivalent MATLAB code to this example would be:

```matlab
>> a = reshape(0:24, [5,5]).';
>> sum(a,2).'
ans =
    10    35    60    85   110
```

Several things to note:

1. The ellipsis operator (`...`) should not be understood as "range", but as "whatever needs to be there".
2. "[Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html)" refers to automatic replication of an array along the relevant dimension so that the mathematical operation is defined. This is a feature that exists in MATLAB since R2016b (called "implicit expansion").
3. You may notice several transpose operations (`.'`) in the MATLAB equivalent. This is because numpy arrays are row-major while MATLAB array are column-major. Practically, while the underlying data has the same sequential order, a numpy array *appears* transposed compared to MATLAB. The transpositions were done so that arrays appear the same in intermediate stages.

---

Another example from these docs is:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape((3,2))
>>> b = np.arange(12).reshape((4,3))
>>> np.einsum('ki,jk->ij', a, b)
array([[10, 28, 46, 64],
       [13, 40, 67, 94]])
>>> np.einsum('ki,...k->i...', a, b)
array([[10, 28, 46, 64],
       [13, 40, 67, 94]])
>>> np.einsum('k...,jk', a, b)
array([[10, 28, 46, 64],
       [13, 40, 67, 94]])
```

Which can be written as follows in MATLAB:

```matlab
A = reshape(0:5, [2 3]).';
B = reshape(0:11, [3 4]).';

A.' * B.'
permute(sum( permute(A, [3 1 2]) .* B,2), [3 1 2])
shiftdim(sum( shiftdim(A, -1) .* B, 2), 2)
```

Several things to note:

1. When going from `np.einsum('ki,jk->ij', a, b)` to `np.einsum('ki,...k->i...', a, b)` you can see that the `j`-th dimension is replaced with `...`. The fact that both these examples have a `->` in them, means it's in *explicit mode*.
2. When going from `np.einsum('ki,jk->ij', a, b)` to `np.einsum('k...,jk', a, b)`, you can see that now the `i`-th dimension is replaced with `...`. The omission of `->...j` simply demonstrates *implicit mode* (where the output dimensions are ordered alphabetically).